# Python: Want to change image HSL like photoshop

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library

I would like to implement this feature(changing HSL with that colorize ticked) in Python, preferable using PIL or maybe numpy.

[image]

Can someone explain how this works?

As far as I know is to use the built-in function color_to_hsl to get the hsl value, change it, then convert ti back to rgb, and finally write to individual pixel.

Any clue to get make it closer?

Comment: With the Colorize box checked, I think you're working with the gray-scale values from the original image as Lightness and setting the Hue and Saturation directly as shown in the dialog. Sorry I don't have time to leave an answer, this is really quite simple though.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845374/how-to-colorize-via-hsl-colors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import colorsys

def colorize(im, h, s, l_adjust):
    h /= 360.0
    s /= 100.0
    l_adjust /= 100.0
    if im.mode != 'L':
        im = im.convert('L')
    result = Image.new('RGB', im.size)
    pixin = im.load()
    pixout = result.load()
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        for x in range(im.size[0]):
            l = pixin[x, y] / 255.99
            l += l_adjust
            l = min(max(l, 0.0), 1.0)
            r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h, l, s)
            r, g, b = int(r * 255.99), int(g * 255.99), int(b * 255.99)
            pixout[x, y] = (r, g, b)
    return result
```

[image: Original]
[image: Colorized]

Comment: Much appreciated! I'm an beginner in image processing, and there will be more image processing I need to do in the future. Would you mind share some links/books in this area?

Comment: @user469652, I'm not sure I can help with any teaching materials as I just picked it up piecemeal over the years. I'm curious though, since I don't have Photoshop does my example match what comes out of it?

Comment: @MarkRansom can you explain the - > min(max(l, 0.0), 1.0)

Comment: @MSI it's a simple way to make sure the value stays within bounds.  `max(l, 0.0)` returns the original value if it's greater than `0.0`, or `0.0` if it isn't.  Likewise `min(l, 1.0)` returns the original value if it's less than `1.0`, or `1.0` if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is what exactly you do in photoshop with colorize check

```
from PIL import Image
import colorsys

def rgbLuminance(r, g, b):
    luminanceR = 0.22248840
    luminanceG = 0.71690369
    luminanceB = 0.06060791
    return (r * luminanceR) + (g * luminanceG) + (b * luminanceB)


def colorize(im, h, s, l_adjust):
    h /= 360.0
    s /= 100.0
    l_adjust /= 100.0
    result = Image.new('RGBA', im.size)
    pixin = im.load()
    pixout = result.load()
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        for x in range(im.size[0]):
            currentR = pixin[x, y][0]/255
            currentG = pixin[x, y][1]/255
            currentB = pixin[x, y][2]/255
            lum = rgbLuminance(currentR, currentG, currentB)
            if l_adjust > 0:
                lum = lum * (1 - l_adjust)
                lum = lum + (1.0 - (1.0 - l_adjust))
            else:
                lum = lum * (l_adjust + 1)
            l = lum
            r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h, l, s)
            r, g, b = int(r * 255.99), int(g * 255.99), int(b * 255.99)
            pixout[x, y] = (r, g, b, 255)
    return result
```