# Shift hue using Pillow

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to know if there's an easy and proper way to shift the hue using Pillow (or an easier alternative with a different library).

I've found a couple of answer about colorizing a picture ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047671/python-want-to-change-image-hsl-like-photoshop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274221/changing-image-hue-with-python-pil)), but I don't want to do that, I just want to shift the hue so the number of colors in the image will be preserved.

Comment: I covered this pretty comprehensively here, I hope https://stackoverflow.com/a/61184434/2836621

Answer (score 4):

Hue shifting can be easily done in HSV space. Using OpenCV:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_bgr = cv2.imread('hue_wheel.jpg')

# convert image from RGB (OpenCV uses BGR order) color space to HSV space
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# H values are in range 0 to 180 
# check: https://docs.opencv.org/master/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_hsv

# shift hue by 180 deg or any other value
n_shift = 180 // 2
img_hsv[:, :, 0] = (img_hsv[:, :, 0].astype(np.int) + n_shift) % 181

# convert hue shifted image back to RGB space
img_bgr_modified = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

cv2.imwrite('hue_wheel_modified.jpg', img_bgr_modified)
```

Input: [image: input] Output: [image: output]